# Behringer Xenyx 1002 mixer to Crown CTs2000 amp

Tags: mixer

Do I have to use both the R and L main output on the Behringer Xenyx 1002 mixer to the channel 1 and channel 2 input on the Crown CTs2000 amplifier?  I would rather use just one output on the mixer and one input on the amplifier if possible.  The amplifier has a "Y" switch to put the same signal on both channels.  I am hooking up a 70v system so I just need a mono signal.  I guess I'm asking if that would hurt the mixer in any way?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can send the left channel from the mixer to the amp and link the two amp channels with no problem. The result will be a mono signal in two channels as you describe yourself.